# Change TimeField and DateField format in views

Tags: python, django

I have a very basic django model:

```
class Day(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()

class Topic(models.Model):
    day = models.ForeignKey(Day)
    time = models.TimeField(choices=CHOICE_TIME)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

So if I access the object's day and time I get these results:

```
>>> topic = Topic.objects.all()[5]
>>> print topic.day
2017-03-13
>>>
>>>
>>> print topic.time
14:00:00
```

I need to use the day in `9 April 2017` format and time in 12 hours format `2 PM` inside the views. How can I solve this? All the answers I found was for django templates, but I need it in views.

Comment: You can override the `__str__` method in your `Day` model to return **'%d %B %Y'.format(...)**. For the `time` issue, you can override `__init__` in your `Topic` model and set `time = time.strftime('%I: %M')`.

Comment: @Wencakisa Okay I will try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `datetime` object(otherwise make it from string using [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime))

```
In [22]: d_obj = datetime.now()

In [23]: d_obj.strftime("%d %B %Y")
Out[23]: '09 April 2017'

In [24]: d_obj.time().strftime('%I:%M %p')
Out[24]: '03:28 PM'
```

In django, `DateTimeField` returns `datetime` object(same as `d_obj` here) and `TimeField` returns `datetime.time` object(same as `d_obj.time()` ).

Comment: `show.time.strftime('%I:%M %p')` does output as expected. But my day field is a `DateField` and not a `DateTimeField`. So, `show.day.strftime("%d %B %Y")` gives an error *Day object has no attribute 'strftime'*

Comment: Post your `Day` class.

Comment: Ok. Now you can do `show.day.date.strftime("%d %B %Y")`

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you.